# How to remove a boot option on a mac?

Tags: macos

If I hold alt/option when my mac is starting up, I get all the possible things I can boot into (MACOSX, BOOTCAMP, RECOVERY etc)

One of them is "EFI boot", which I had when I installed linux.
Now I have deleted all the linux sda's (root, swap, home etc), but this is still here.

If I choose that option it just shows a static screen, where it mentions Grub.

So does anyone know (rhetoric) how to remove this from the "boot list" ?

Also if I decide to get rid of windows then how should I remove the BOOTCAMP entry (same process ?) or is removing an OS and its corresponding "entry" something that should be done somehow "in one go" ?

Thanks a lot in advance !

Answer (score 1):

If you install rEFIt I think you have an option to hide the entry, but not erase it. Knowing how touchy the boot sector is on a mac especially with Boot Camp I would be inclined to leave it.

In regards to removing windows in the future, the Boot Camp utility will remove the partition and the entry at boot, and recover the disc space back to osx.

Answer (score 0):

Install Windows using BootCamp again, and then remove it using BootCamp Assistant. It takes time, but erases dummy Windows entries forever. I didn't regret the time spent.

Comment: Will doing that remove the "EFI Boot", or just the Bootcamp entry?

Comment: Didn't work for me. The Windows Recovery "EFI Boot" entry is still there after restoring to only an OSX existence via "Bootcamp Assistant" as suggested.